# Sendmail - preventing aliased users from receiving multiple copies of the same email

Tags: email, sendmail, alias, mailing-list

Is there any way to prevent a user from receiving multiple copies of the same email if an email is sent to both an alias for the user as well as the user themselves?

For example, suppose **bob.smith** is a included in the alias list for **developers (@company.com)**

If I send the email to both the user and an alias for the user:

```
To: bob.smith@company.com, developers@company.com
```

... is there any way to prevent user Bob from receiving the same email two times?

EDIT: I've observed that if Bob is a member of two different alias groups, and I send an email just to those two groups (not the user directly), sendmail correctly expands the groups and removes the duplicate. The behavior I want to fix occurs when you send directly to the user AND a group they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you're looking for...but a long, long time ago I had my `procmail` rules set up filter out duplicate messages by message-id, so that only the first one would get delivered.  Like [this](http://ramblings.narrabilis.com/wp/filtering-duplicate-emails-with-procmail/).

Note that I'm not actually recommending this as a solution :).